# no operator ">>" matches these operands. Nested structs & dynamic allocation

Tags: c++

I created two structs, one to hold information of a person and one to hold how many layers of clothing he is wearing and what they are.

```
const int sizeOfLayerName = 20;
    struct Layers {
        char* layerName[sizeOfLayerName];
    };

    struct Person {
        Layers* layer;
    };
}
```

I'm able to define how many layers the person is wearing, however I can't input what kind of layer it is (example: sweater) due to the error stated in the title.

```
int main() {
    int layers;
    cout << "How many layers is the person wearing: ";
    cin >> layers;

    Layers* layer = nullptr;
    layer = new Layers[layers];

    for (int i = 0; i < layers; i++) {
        cout << "What is the person wearing for layer " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> layer[i].layerName; // Error occurs here
        cout << "Layer" << i + 1 << ": " << layer[i].layerName;
    }
}
```

I looked at other similar questions, so I did try those solutions like including different libraries:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
```

but I still get the error. So I am just assuming it's the code itself.

Comment: why array of pointers to char?  Maybe what you want is `char layerName[sizeOfLayerName]`

Comment: what they said. also, this will crash if input is too long. use `std::string` for `layerName`.

Comment: you've also got a dangling `}`

Comment: you have memory leaks and other problems which all can be avoided completely if you stop messing around with `new` and bare pointers and use `std::vector` and `std::string` instead.

Comment: The error will show you where in your code the compiler is having trouble. The error will also show the operand types. It's polite to include _everything_ the compiler already gave you for free, instead of forcing readers to try and figure it out.